# consultar 360,000 codigos de manera rapida java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle-11g

Tengo 1 Query principal cuyo tiempo de respuesta es optimo, el problema surge cuando despues de ejecutar mi query dentro del while ejecuto un segundo query que me lee el campo codigo y consulta de 1 por uno, aqui mi codig :

```
$_Query ="select * from remesas";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery($_Query);
while(rs.next()){
 String SQLDevo ="SELECT DEVO.TIPO,CASE WHEN DEVO.TIPO='ER' THEN 'SF' WHEN DEVO.TIPO='EC' THEN 'BP'WHEN DEVO.TIPO='DR' THEN 'DV' end as clave,' ' as csituacion,COALESCE(DEVO.NOMBRE||' '||DEVO.APELLIDO_PATERNO||' '||DEVO.APELLIDO_MATERNO ,' ') AS NOMBRE, "
                        + " COALESCE(DEVO.VISITA,' ') AS NUM_VISITAS,COALESCE(DEVO.NUM_IDENTIFICADOR,' ') AS NUM_IDENTIFICADOR ,COALESCE(S1.TAG,' ') AS TAG,  "
                        + " TO_CHAR(DEVO.FECHA,'DD-MM-YYYY') AS FECHA,COALESCE(TO_CHAR(FECHA_ENTREGA,'DD-MM-YYYY'),' ') AS FECHA_ENTREGA,"
                        + " CASE WHEN TIPO ='EC' THEN "
                        + " DOMICILIO||'|PISOS'||'|'||COLOR_DOMICILIO||'|'||S1.DESCRIPTION||'|'|| "
                        + " CASE  "
                        + " WHEN REJA_BARDA = 'N' THEN 'SIN/REJA'  "
                        + " WHEN REJA_BARDA = 'S' THEN 'CON/REJA' "
                        + " END ||'|'||  "
                        + " CASE "
                        + " WHEN COCHERA_TEJADA = 'N' THEN 'SIN/COCHERA' "
                        + " WHEN COCHERA_TEJADA = 'S' THEN 'CON/COCHERA' "
                        + " END  "
                        + " WHEN S2.DESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL THEN S2.DESCRIPTION"
                        + " ELSE '|'|| S2.DESCRIPTION "
                        + "  END AS COMENTARIOS, "
                        + " COALESCE(S2.TAG,' ') AS TAG2,COALESCE(S3.DESCRIPTION,' ') AS DESCRIPTION,COALESCE(S4.DESCRIPTION,' ') AS DESCRIPTION2,COALESCE(S5.TAG,' ') as MOTIVO,COALESCE(S5.ATTRIBUTE3,' ') AS MOTIVOCLIENTE  "
                        + " FROM XXQP.XXQP_DEVOLUCIONES_LN_TBL DEVO  "
                        + " LEFT JOIN ( "
                        + " SELECT TAG,DESCRIPTION FROM APPLSYS.FND_LOOKUP_VALUES LV WHERE  LV.LOOKUP_TYPE  = 'XXQP_PARENTESCO' AND LV.LANGUAGE='ESA' "
                        + " ) S1 ON S1.DESCRIPTION = DEVO.PARENTESCO "
                        + " LEFT JOIN ( "
                        + " SELECT TAG,DESCRIPTION FROM  APPLSYS.FND_LOOKUP_VALUES LV WHERE  LV.LOOKUP_TYPE = 'XXQP_IDENTIFICACION' AND LV.LANGUAGE='ESA' "
                        + " ) S2 ON S2.DESCRIPTION = DEVO.IDENTIFICADOR  "
                        + " LEFT JOIN ( "
                        + " SELECT DESCRIPTION,LOOKUP_CODE FROM APPLSYS.FND_LOOKUP_VALUES LV WHERE LV.LOOKUP_TYPE = 'XXQP_TIPOS_PUERTA' AND LV.LANGUAGE='ESA' "
                        + " ) S3 ON S3.LOOKUP_CODE = DEVO.TIPO_PUERTA  "
                        + " LEFT JOIN ( "
                        + " SELECT DESCRIPTION,LOOKUP_CODE FROM APPLSYS.FND_LOOKUP_VALUES LV WHERE LV.LOOKUP_TYPE = 'XXQP_ESTATUS_MEDIDOR' AND LV.LANGUAGE='ESA' "
                        + " ) S4 ON  S4.LOOKUP_CODE =DEVO.MEDIDOR "
                        + " LEFT JOIN ( "
                        + " SELECT TAG,DESCRIPTION,ATTRIBUTE3,ATTRIBUTE2 FROM APPLSYS.FND_LOOKUP_VALUES LV WHERE LV.LOOKUP_TYPE = 'XXQP_MOTIVOS_PLATINUM' AND LV.LANGUAGE='ESA' "
                        + " ) S5 ON S5.DESCRIPTION= DEVO.MOTIVO  AND S5.ATTRIBUTE2 =" + rs.getString("cliente_id")
                        + " WHERE  ROWNUM<2 AND DEVO.CODIGO_QP= " + rs.getString("CODIGO_QP") ;
ResultSet rsSegundo = stSegundo.executeQuery(SQLDevo);
if(rsSegundo.next()){
   Nombre = rsSegundo.getString("NOMBRE");
   Num_Visitas = rsSegundo.getString("NUM_VISITAS");
   Num_Identificador = rsSegundo.getString("NUM_IDENTIFICADOR");
}
}
```

Entonces si tengo 1000 rows en mi primer query si los procesa bien, pero cuando entra en el segundo query consultar de 1 por uno.

Como pudiese mejorar este proceso?

Saludos.

Comment: cuanto estas dispuesto a modificar tu codigo y los querys??? se puede hacer con joins, con where IN, hay multples metodos..

Comment: Mi pregunta principal sería: ¿qué deseas hacer con la información que extraes de la base de datos? Con base en tu respuesta se plantea una o más soluciones. Si no deseas realizar grandes modificaciones al código yo recomendaría obtener toda la info de la tabla `remesas` y toda la info de `devoluciones` y realizar la lógica directamente en código así como en tu base de datos indexaría la columna `codigo_qp` para que la consulta sea más eficaz

Comment: He actualizado el query secundario... el detalle es que se construyo un query con multiples left join y al momento de querer incorporarlo al query principal demora mucho en devolver la respuesta, el usuario por lo general procesa informacion de 1 mes, entonces si es mucho proceso

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que estás haciendo 1 query para traer los ids que quieres consultar, y luego un segundo query que se ejecuta **por cada uno de los resultados del anterior query**, lo que significa que si tu primer query trajo 1000 filas, luego haces 1000 consultas a la base de datos. No importa cuánto optimices tu query, simplemente el problema es cómo lo estás haciendo.

Lo mejor sería usar un `JOIN` y así ejecutar un solo query:

```
select s.*
from devoluciones d
    inner join remesas r
where d.codigo_qp = r.codigo_qp
```

Y de este query (1 sola ejecución), leer los datos que realmente necesites.

Comment: He actualizado el query secundario... el detalle es que se construyo un query con multiples left join y al momento de querer incorporarlo al query principal demora mucho en devolver la respuesta, el usuario por lo general procesa informacion de 1 mes, entonces si es mucho proceso

Comment: La idea es la misma. Debes cambiar tu query para que solo te devuelta los datos que buscas en 1 sola ejecución.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrás mejor rendimiento si lo haces todo en una sola consulta de una vez con un join:

```sql
select d.*
  from remesas r
  join devoluciones d
    on d.codigo_qp = r.codigo_qp
```

Comment: He actualizado el query secundario... el detalle es que se construyo un query con multiples left join y al momento de querer incorporarlo al query principal demora mucho en devolver la respuesta, el usuario por lo general procesa informacion de 1 mes, entonces si es mucho proceso

Comment: @Jairo: Esa información viene a cambiar la pregunta totalmente. Aunque es cierto que el principio de ejecutar una sola consulta sigue aplicando, pero viendo la complejidad de tu consulta secundaria, hay una muy alta probabilidad de que tienes problemas con esa consulta por sí sola que no resolverán simplememente por juntar las 2 consultas. Para recibir ayuda adecuada, debes incluir la información siguiente a tu pregunta: 1) descripción completa de todas las tablas envueltas, particularmente, cuales índices tienen, 2) cantidad de registros por tabla, 3) explain plan para la segunda consulta.

Comment: Y si el query primario es diferente a lo que pusistes en tu pregunta, por favor, modifícala para reflejar la realidad.